# As ... as possible, as soon as possible

Tags: phrases, idiom-requests, writing-style, phrase-requests

Recently I had to write the following to indicate significance of both the urgency and completeness regarding some task to be done:

> We would like to be able to install as many parts of the system as possible, as soon as possible.

I would like to know if this is acceptable, or are there any better ways to express this without repetition of *possible* in the phrase `as ... as possible, as soon as possible`?

Comment: Yes, the full repetition means they are each to be emphasized.

Comment: "As many parts as possible" and "as soon as possible" mean entirely different things.  It's not repetition for emphasis.  In some cases it's good to avoid repeating the same word, to not sound "weird" or seem uncreative, but in the above example it's perfectly fine.

Comment: It's repetition of the full structure -- with all the bells and whistles attached -- for each item, to emphasize that they are in fact **not** the same thing, and are each important.

Comment: Great, thanks. No alternatives were suggested, so would any of you care to formulate this as an answer?